# UIAlertView within XML Parser didEndElement not showing

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsxmlparser, uialertview

I am working on an iphone application. Application uses .net web service to perform an operation and return the status either "Success" or "Failure".

I am getting this status in xml parser didEndElement like

```
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"OperationStatusResult"])
{

}
```

I am trying to show an UIAlert view if status is failure within didEndElement but it does not show. Is there anything I am missing here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am trying to show an UIAlert view if status is failure within didEndElement but it does not show. Is there anything I am missing here.*

If you are running the XML parsing in a background thread, make sure you [perform the UI update on the main thread](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF).

Put your `UIAlertView` code into a selector in your view controller and use the `-performSelectorOnMainThread...` method to fire off the alert view, if the status fails.

Comment: My application is not multi-threadred. I am running this on the main thread.

Comment: Perhaps you might add the code showing how you are instantiating the alert view.